# How to get timedelta in seconds from a string? Example: +414 00:45:41.004000

Tags: python, timedelta

I have data of timedeltas which looks like this:

```
time_delta = '+414 00:45:41.004000'
```

So, these values are strings and they are of the format `ddd hh:mm:ss.f`. I now want to get this deltas to seconds. I tried to use `.total_seconds()` but it did not work.

How could I achieve what I am trying to do?

Comment: why don't you parse as a string and extract?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you always assume the same input format, you can build a function as below (result to be checked with a simple case) :

```
import datetime as dt

def parseTimeDelta(time_delta_str):
     splitted = time_delta_str.split(' ')
     day_part = int(splitted[0][1:])
     time_part = dt.datetime.strptime(splitted[1], "%H:%M:%S.%f")
     delta = dt.timedelta(days=day_part, hours=time_part.hour, minutes=time_part.minute, seconds=time_part.second,microseconds=time_part.microsecond)
     return delta.total_seconds()

time_delta = '+414 00:45:41.004000'
parseTimeDelta(time_delta)
```

Answer (score 1):

can do this with `pandas` [library](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Timedelta.html#pandas-timedelta)

```
import pandas as pd  
  
# Create the Timedelta object  
td = pd.Timedelta('3 days 06:05:01.000000111')  
  
print(td)  
  
print(td.seconds)
```

Comment: Thanks, that is cool! Is it also possible to get decimal values?

Comment: you can use `td.values`

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately we can't create a timedelta with a formatted string directly, but we can get a similar effect with regex then unpack parsed values into a timedelta.

```py
import re
import datetime

# Create parser for your time format with named groups that match timedelta kwargs
time_parser = re.compile(r"\+(?P<days>\d+)\s+(?P<hours>\d{2}):(?P<minutes>\d{2}):(?P<seconds>\d{2})\.(?P<microseconds>\d+)")

# Get the values from your example string
regex_match = time_parser.match("+414 00:45:41.004000")
time_dict = regex_match.groupdict()

# Convert the time values to integers from strings
timedelta_kwargs = {k: int(v) for k, v in time_dict.items()}

# Make a time delta object
delta = datetime.timedelta(**timedelta_kwargs)

# Get total seconds
delta_in_seconds = delta.total_seconds()
```

Organise that into some functions and you'll get the functionality you're looking for with standard python packages.